# VS Code + Remote SSH + sh: bash: not found

Tags: vscode-remote-ssh

I try to connect to but everytimes i have :

```
        [10:25:51.238] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files\Python310\ssh.exe ENOENT
[10:25:51.689] > Admin@192.168.0.1's password:]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[10:25:51.689] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[10:25:51.707] > Admin@192.168.0.1's password:
> 
> 
[10:25:57.525] > 
[10:25:57.692] > Could not chdir to home directory /var/services/homes/Admin: No such file or directory
[10:25:57.721] > sh: bash: not found
[10:25:59.000] "install" terminal command done
[10:25:59.000] Install terminal quit with output: sh: bash: not found
[10:25:59.000] Received install output: sh: bash: not found
[10:25:59.003] Resolver error: Error: bash introuvable
    at m.Create (c:\Users\MyUser\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:584145)
    at c:\Users\MyUser\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:582093
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\MyUser\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:582627)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\MyUser\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:681555)
    at async c:\Users\Jamyz\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:643798
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\MyUser\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:647116)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\MyUser\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:644848)
    at async c:\Users\MyUser\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:720590
[10:25:59.008] ------
```

How add bash to run with linux?
I have bash in C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Thanks you